# How do you copy a CALayer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation, calayer

How can you make an NSArray full of multiple instances of a CALayer (all with the same frame, contents etc)?

Background: CALayer takes a bit of overhead to create, so I would like to create a number of CALayers (all sharing the same properties) in the init method of a class (to be used later on in that class.)

Comment: Why do you need to copy them? Why not create them all from scratch or, reduce the number of layers your app needs?

Comment: yes, that's an option (creating them all from scratch), but its not terribly elegant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CALayer doesn't have a built in `-(id)copy` method.  I'm not sure why.  It's not difficult to gin up your own however.  Create a CALayer category and write your own copy method.  All you have to do is instantiate and manually get the public ivars/properties from the original and set to the new copy.  Don't forget to call `[super copy]`

BTW, CALayer is an object.  You can add it to an NSArray.

Answer (score 26):

I haven't tried this with `CALayer` specifically, but I know you can perform a deep-copy by taking advantage of `NSCoding`:

`CALayer *layer = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:layer]];`

I'm not sure how copying them would really help with performance, though.

Comment: Here's an update for you. Thanks again. stackoverflow.com/a/68006776/1058199

Answer (score 2):

Try to use CAReplicatorLayer.  It can duplicate your layers.

reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/careplicatorlayer

sample code: http://www.knowstack.com/swift-careplicatorlayer-sample-code/
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/careplicatorlayer/1522391-instancedelay

Comment: Super helpful.  Better than the top answer.

Answer (score 2):

An updated link to MaxGabriel's top rated answer.

Objective-C

```
CALayer *layer1;
CALayer *layer2;

// Set up layer1's specifics.

layer2 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:[CALayer class]
                                                            fromData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:layer1 requiringSecureCoding:NO error:nil] error:nil];
```

And in Swift.

```
let layer1: CALayer?
var layer2: CALayer? = nil
// Set up layer1's specifics

do {
    layer2 = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(
        ofClass: CALayer.self,
        from: try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: layer1, requiringSecureCoding: false))
} catch {
// It failed.  Do something. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do exactly the same thing in my program.

In init:

```
    self.turrets = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (count = 0; count < kMaxTurrets; count++)
        [self spawnTurret];
```

spawnTurret:

```
evTurret* aTurret = [[[evTurret alloc] init] autorelease];
CGImageRef theImage = [self turretContents];
aTurret.contents = theImage;
double imageHeight = CGImageGetHeight(theImage);
double imageWidth = CGImageGetWidth(theImage);
double turretSize = 0.06*(mapLayer.bounds.size.width + mapLayer.bounds.size.height)/2.0;
aTurret.bounds = CGRectMake(-turretSize*0.5, turretSize*0.5, turretSize*(imageWidth/imageHeight), turretSize);
aTurret.hidden = YES;
[mapLayer addSublayer:aTurret]; 
[self.turrets addObject:aTurret];
```

Basically, just I just repeatedly create CALayer objects. It's going to be faster than copying them, as this method only requires 1 CALayer call per property, as opposed to copying it which requires you to read the property and then additionally set it. I spawn about 500 objects using this method in about 0.02 seconds, so it's definitely fast. If you really needed more speed you could even cache the image file.

Comment: That doesn't really help.  The question is about copying or duplicating layers.

Answer (score 0):

NSProxy is used for that reason. What you're describing is a common scenario, and one from which any number of design patterns are derived.

Pro Objective-C Design Patterns for iOS provides the solution to the very problem you describe; read Chapter 3: The Protoype Pattern. Here's a summary definition:

The Prototype pattern specifies the kind of objects to create using a prototypical instance, whereby a new object is created by copying this instan

Answer (score 0):

Although it's best to use [`CAReplicatorLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/careplicatorlayer) for your use case,
others may really need to copy `CALayer`, so I'm here writing another answer.
*(I had to copy because of `CARenderer`)*

I tried `NSKeyedArchiver` as well, it works mostly, but some functionality get broken for complex `CALayer`
*(for me, it was the mask with filters)*

## implementation

Implementation is pretty straightforward.

1. Make new `CALayer`.
2. Copy properties that you need/use.
3. Do it recursively for sublayers and mask.

Here is an example for `CAShapeLayer`:

```swift
extension CALayer {
    func deepCopy() -> CAShapeLayer {
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.frame = frame
        layer.bounds = bounds
        layer.filters = filters
        layer.contents = contents
        layer.contentsScale = contentsScale
        layer.masksToBounds = masksToBounds
        //add or remove lines for your need

        if let self = self as? CAShapeLayer {
            layer.path = self.path?.copy()
            layer.lineCap = self.lineCap
            layer.lineJoin = self.lineJoin
            layer.lineWidth = self.lineWidth
            layer.fillColor = self.fillColor
            layer.strokeColor = self.strokeColor
            //add or remove lines for your need
        }

        layer.mask = mask?.deepCopy()
        layer.sublayers = sublayers?.map { $0.deepCopy() }
        return layer
    }
}
```